# Is there a greasemonkey for IE? or, how do I get a website to use MSXML6 instead of MSXML5?

Tags: internet-explorer, greasemonkey, msxml

I don't know greasemonkey but I think it is a way to script or extend Firefox.

Is there a greasemonkey for IE?

*for example*: There's a website that is hosting a page that asks me to install MSXML5.0.

[image]

[I don't want MSXML5.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx).
I was thinking if I had a greasemonkey capability (if it is what I think it is), I'd be able to write a script that changes the 5.0 to 6.0 and everything would be cool.

I know there's a way to do this kind of thing in Fiddler, if I have it running, and set up as a proxy.

Comment: Why don't you want to install MSXML5.0? It doesn't overwrite 6.0.

Comment: I don't want MSXML 5.0 because of the reasoning laid out in the blog post I referenced above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. [IEPro](http://www.ie7pro.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Hey I know this is a bit old but alternatively there is Trixie. At this point the main site is down but I got an archive of the installer from [this location](http://web.archive.org/web/20100917214025/http://bhelpuri.net/Trixie/TrixieDownload.htm). Unfortunately there isn't an active project nor is there an open-source solution available at this time but this will get you up and running.